# Solve equation for a given set of parameters

Tags: survival, exponential-distribution, integral, inverse-problem

I'm modelling a process for which the probability of the event (stop) not happening before time $t$ is $e^{-\lambda\cdot t }|\lambda>0$. When the event happens, the process stops running for a constant time $\kappa > 0$. After this time has passed, the process restarts.

For a time horizon, $\tau > 0$, using $N = \left\lceil\frac{\tau}{\kappa}\right\rceil-1$ and $\delta_i = \tau - i\cdot \kappa$ the expected active time is:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^N \int_0^{\delta_i} e^{-\lambda\cdot t}\cdot(1- e^{-\lambda\cdot t})^i dt = \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^N\frac{(1- e^{-\lambda\cdot \delta_i})^{(i+1)}}{i + 1} = Res $$

Is there a closed form to recover $\tau$ given $\kappa, \lambda, Res $?

If not, what is the recommended approach?

Comment: You write *"for a time horizon, $\tau > 0$"*, and what that means is not clear. The reader would be able to figure it out reading the formula, but because you include complicated and not intuitively explained parameters $N$ and $\delta_i$ (and $\tau$ is not directly visible in the formula) it is difficult to imagine what you are doing and what 'time horizon' means. (I am not saying it is impossible and I have an idea, but I feel that you could describe the problem a bit more simple)

Comment: Probably, it was complex to explain. $\tau$ represents a time horizon (end of day). The $\delta$ is used to make the formula easier to read.

Comment: Possibly you can simplify the equations by assuming $\tau = 1$. The time scale is arbitrary anyway.

Comment: Your computation of $Res$ seems to be computing how often you have the stops, but does it also take into account the possibility that the stop is occurring at the boundary of the horizon and not fully inside the time period?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus sorry for the late response, I was on vacation, and I didn't check my question. The calculation of $Res$ considers the boundary $\tau - i \cdot\kappa>0$. My doubt would be how to get $\tau$ from a given $Res$. I think the solution has to be reach using numeric methods due to the step function, but I was wondering if a closed solution exists.

Comment: I already have doubts about whether your formula for $Res$ is actually computing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I already have doubts about whether your formula for $Res$ is actually computing what you want. Consider $\tau < \kappa < 2  \tau$, then $N = 1$ and according to your computation $$Res = \frac{1}{\lambda} \left( 1-e^{-\lambda \cdot \tau}\right) +  \frac{1}{2\lambda} \left( 1-e^{-\lambda \cdot (\tau-\kappa)}\right)^{1/2}$$

When I compute this alternatively by simulation, then I get a difference, 0.948 for the simulation versus 0.974 for the formula.

[image: example]

```
set.seed(1)
tau = 1.5
kappa = 1
lambda = 1

### computation 
expectation = (1-exp(-lambda*tau))/lambda + (1-exp(-lambda*(tau-kappa)))/lambda/2

### simulation 
sim = function() {
   t = rexp(2,lambda)
   time = tau
   if (t[1] < tau) {
       time = t[1]
       if (t[1] < tau-kappa) {
         if (t[1]+t[2] < tau) {
           time = t[1] + t[2]
         } else {
           time = tau - kappa
         }
       }
   } 
   time
}


### compute simulations and plot histogram 
t = replicate(10^6,sim())
hist(t, freq = 0,breaks = seq(0,tau,0.01))

### compare estimates
mean(t)       # 0.9476016
expectation   # 0.9736045
```

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to debug your code. There is a bug on your nested if  `if(t[1]+t[2] < tau)` should be `tau-kappa` and the expectation should be `expectation = (1 - exp(-lambda * tau)) / lambda +
  ((1 - exp(-lambda * (tau - kappa))) ^ 2) / lambda / 2`